# Convert cUrl comnad lines to PHP lines

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, curl

I have a `curl` command that I can successfully run from a Linux (ubuntu) command line.

I would need to incorporate this `curl` command in a PHP script.

How can I translate the below curl command so that it works in a PHP script?

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/rdf+xml" -F recipe=http://demo/recipe_alta -F input=@prova_rdf.rdf http://site.cs.unibo.it/stanbol/refactor
```

I've been trying a lot of calls in PHP I've found on the internet but I always get *http 409 and 415 messages*.

I tried also `exec` and `shell_exec` but I get the same errors.

this is another call, just for posting the rdf file on the url, and i get the same errors.

```
$url = "http://bernina.cs.unibo.it/stanbol/triplestore/grafotest_cavo";
$post_data['file'] = "@prova_rdf.rdf";
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array('Accept: application/rdf+xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Please show the PHP code that you have tried.

Comment: read the curl section of the php manual. You'll have plenty of examples there

Comment: read above, i edit the post